Unable to Connect the remote server in the production environment , Works into the local . Also same url works into the postman
I'm encountering an issue where my application is unable to connect to a remote API server in the production environment, throwing the error:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to connect to the remote server
However:

The same API works perfectly fine in my local environment.

The API call also works in Postman with the exact same request details.


https://api.example.com/readmeter?key=YourAPIKey&cnt=10000&format=json&timezone=America~New_York&devices=DeviceID&start_date=22112024&end_date=25112024
Verified the API Endpoint:

Tested the API in Postman and my local environment, where it works perfectly.

Expected: The API to work similarly in production.

Result: Fails with Unable to connect to the remote server.


public async Task<JsonResult> getAPIData(string fromDate, string toDate, string meter, string apiKey)
{
    var data = "";
    var logs = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        logs.Add("API call started.");

        // Security protocol configuration
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        // Base URL from configuration
        var baseUrl = "https://api.example.com/";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        // Construct the final URL
        var apiUrl = $"readmeter?key={apiKey}&cnt=10000&format=json&timezone=America~New_York&devices={meter}&start_date={fromDate}&end_date={toDate}";
        logs.Add($"API URL: {client.BaseAddress}{apiUrl}");

        // Make the API call
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            logs.Add("API call successful.");
            string resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Process response here...
        }
        else
        {
            logs.Add($"API failed. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logs.Add($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            logs.Add($"Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
        }
    }

    return Json(new { data, logs }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


Firewall / security settings? Can you generally access HTTPS endpoints in this production environment? If no, it's a security setting on your end. If yes, it's a security restriction on the API you're calling (on their end).

Production environment is on the IONOS . So is there any problem in the ionos ?
